# How to compare data types of 2 tables in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way wherein I will be able to compare data types of 2 tables in MS Access? I have one table with 66 columns with specified names (Like ID, Name, ETc...) and another table that will be autogenerated based on an extract with the same number of columns but the field names default (F1, F2, F3, ... F66) so would like to check if there is a way in access that I can compare the data types of 66 columns from both tables? Thanks Much! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some VBA to loop the `Fields` collection of each table. Something like this should get you started:

```
Sub sCompareTables(strTable1 As String, strTable2 As String)
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf1 As DAO.TableDef
    Dim tdf2 As DAO.TableDef
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tdf1 = db.TableDefs(strTable1)
    Set tdf2 = db.TableDefs(strTable2)
    If tdf1.Fields.Count = tdf2.Fields.Count Then
        For lngLoop1 = 0 To tdf1.Fields.Count - 1
            If tdf1.Fields(lngLoop1).Type = tdf2.Fields(lngLoop1).Type Then
                Debug.Print "Match: " & tdf1.Fields(lngLoop1).name & vbTab & tdf2.Fields(lngLoop1).name & vbTab & fDatatype(tdf1.Fields(lngLoop1).Type)
            Else
                Debug.Print "No Match: " & tdf1.Fields(lngLoop1).name & vbTab & tdf2.Fields(lngLoop1).name & vbTab & fDatatype(tdf1.Fields(lngLoop1).Type) & "|" & fDatatype(tdf2.Fields(lngLoop1).Type)
            End If
        Next lngLoop1
    Else
        Debug.Print "Field counts do not match"
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set tdf1 = Nothing
    Set tdf2 = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sCompareTables", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub

Function fDatatype(lngDatatype As Long) As String
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Select Case lngDatatype
        Case 4
            fDatatype = "Long"
        Case 8
            fDatatype = "Date"
        Case 10
            fDatatype = "Text"
        Case 12
            fDatatype = "Memo"
        Case Else
            fDatatype = "Unknown"
    End Select
fExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "fDatatype", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume fExit
End Function
```

The function `fDatatype` that I've created does not list all of the available datatypes that are available - you can see a full list by pressing F2 to bring up the Object Browser, and searching for something like `dbText` to see all members of the `DAO.DataTypeEnum` class.

Comment: apologies for the delay in response.. I tried and works perfectly!! Thanks !! :)